# error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have written a callback method and when I am trying to compile the project in vs2012, I am getting the following error:

```
 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
```

the both error present in same line.

These are the following code which I am trying:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "atlstr.h"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class CInf;
typedef BOOL (*PENUMDEVCALLBACK)(CInf* inf, const CString& devname, const CString& instsecname, const CStringArray& devid, PVOID context, DWORD& code);
```

I think the error will be present in `CStringArray&` argument because when I include the `afxcoll.h`.

`the fatal error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>.`

When I removed the windows.h. the above error gone but I need windows.h header also.

Any idea how to include `windows.h` and `afxcoll.h` in same file.

Comment: I believe you are supposed to include `afx.h` and then `afxcoll.h`. The former (indirectly) includes `windows.h`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to include only isolated parts of the MFC. When you want to use CStringArray you Need to include the afx.h or afxwin.h file.

It is possible to use CString alone. If you just want an Array of CString and you don't Need the complete MFC than it is easier to use std::vector. CString works perfect with all STL container.